# jQuery using delay() with hide()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I have the following script which shows / hides a dropdown menu when `#icon-hamburger` is clicked. The menu has a short fading animation when showing / hiding:

```
// nav-mobile
$('#icon-hamburger, .icon-close').click(function() {
    if ($('.nav-mobile').css('opacity') === '0') {

        $('.nav-mobile').show();
        $('.nav-mobile').animate({
            'opacity': '1'

        },

        250, function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    }
    if ($('.nav-mobile').css('opacity') === '1') {
        $('.nav-mobile').animate({
            'opacity': '0'
        },

        250, function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
        $('.nav-mobile').delay(250).hide();
    }
    return false;
});
```

The menu fades in just fine, but instead of fading out it just disappears. I would have thought the following line would allow the element to fade out before being hidden?:

```
$('.nav-mobile').delay(250).hide();
```

Comment: One thing I would make sure to change is change `if ($('.nav-mobile').css('opacity') === '1') {` to `else if ($('.nav-mobile').css('opacity') === '1') {`. The way your code is right now, is if opacity is 0, animate to 1. Then right after that your opacity is 1, animate back to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$('.nav-mobile').delay(250).hide(200);

add some duration in hide function so it will hide out with some animation .

if you want to fade out element use .fadeOut(200) instead of .hide(200) function.

Answer (score -1):

Click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/h49sbngx/) for a JSFiddle example. Inspect the Element.

The menu is still there. It's not hiding. Just opacity get's zero.

Just remove the jQuery hide code.

```
$('.nav-mobile').delay(250).hide();
```